# wp8 DataBase doesn't work~

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want use a database in my app, but there are some errors:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

It occurs on this:

```
 if (true == db.PersonData.Any())
```

and

```
db.PersonData.InsertOnSubmit(newData);
```

The code worked on wp7....how do you fix it?

Thx~

```
[Table]
public class CPersonData
{
    [Column]
    public string Lat { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Lon { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string SelectShopType { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
}

public class DataBase : DataContext
{
    public Table<CPersonData> PersonData;

    public DataBase(string strConnection) : base(strConnection)
    {
        if (false == this.DatabaseExists())
            this.CreateDatabase();
    }
}

using (var db = new DataBase("Data Source=isostore:/FindTea.sdf"))
{
    CPersonData newData = new CPersonData();
    newData.Lat = "";
    newData.Lon = "";
    newData.SelectShopType = "1,2,3";
    db.PersonData.InsertOnSubmit(newData);
    db.SubmitChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: I think you need to paste more code to make sense of what your problem is... Please do it...

Comment: What's the exception message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!!!I didn't put a primary key in this table, so when I add this

```
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, CanBeNull = false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

The App doesn't crash!!!!